# How to add only relative path with PHP ZipArchive::addPattern?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

As simple as the title:

```
$zipFileName = $folderName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . strtolower(sprintf('bundle_%s.zip', date('F_Y', strtotime('last month'))));

$zip = new \ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($zipFileName, \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
    throw new \Exception("cannot open <$zipFileName>\n", 500);
}

$zip->addPattern('/\.csv$/', $folderName, ['remove_path' => $folderName]);
$zip->close();
```

This is creating a zip file with the path as the absolute path on the machine:

So I'm opening the resulting zip and having:

```
/tmp/bundle/file1.csv
/tmp/bundle/file2.csv
/tmp/bundle/file3.csv
```

But, I would like to get:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Not sure what else to try?

Comment: Did you try `'remove_all_path' => true`

Comment: Yeap... Also, I tried the addGlob function like:

$zip->addGlob($folderName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "*.csv", GLOB_BRACE , ['remove_all_path' => TRUE]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $zip         = new \ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($zipFullPath, \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Cannot open <$zipFullPath>\n", 500);
    }
    foreach(glob($folderName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*') as $file)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
    }
    $zip->close();
```

This is how I ended up doing it. No luck with addPattern function.

Answer (score 0):

This (in linux) worked for me:

```
$zip->addPattern($pattern, $path, ["add_path" => "./" , "remove_all_path" => true]);
```